# Should we allow simple questions?

Tags: discussion

Not all questions are made equal. Some require expert knowledge, some can be sufficiently answered by a dictionary. Should we allow the second kind, and if we don't, where do we draw the line?

Comment: I think "simple" questions will more often than expected still be good questions, but "trivial" questions will never be good for the site.

Answer (score 9):

I think the line is **research effort**.

If the OP provides evidence of it, then any question is fine, even the simplest ones. I also agree with Vladimir.

Answer (score 7):

I think simple how-to-translate questions should be allowed if they there's some context provided that does not allow to use translation from dictionary or topic-starter explained why he can't use dictionary, e.g.

**Bad:**

> How to translate "A" to Russian

**OK:**

> How to translate *A* to Russian in the phrase "Blabla *A* blabla"

**OK:**

> How to translate *A* to Russian? I checked the dictionary and there's *А* and *Б* options which one is more appropriate in my case (case explanation followed)

Comment: That seems like a good policy to me for translation questions, but it's not like we're going to be dealing with translation questions exclusively.